# Comparing two arrays of hashes using sets in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Following this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574776/ruby-comparing-two-arrays-of-hashes) I am trying to compare two arrays of hashes:

```
db = [
{:foo => "bar", :stack => "overflow", :num => 0.5},
{:foo => "bar", :stack => "underlow", :num => 0.5},
{:foo => "bar", :stack => "overflow", :num => 0.1}
]

csv = [
{:foo => "bar", :stack => "overflow", :num => 0.5},
{:foo => "bar", :stack => "underlow", :num => 0.1},
]
```

I am trying to use a Ruby Set (`db_set = Set[db]`, `csv_set = Set[csv]`) to compare the two using `-` (`db_set - csv_set`) and `&` (`db_set & csv_set`) but these do not appear to be performing the compare operations.

Have i misunderstood the use of `Set`? How can i compare these two arrays of hashes?

Comment: do you want to compare (this array is less than that array) or perform set operations?

Comment: I would like to perform set operations, ie return which hahses are common to both, which are not in one or the other etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to use sets here. Seems that you'll be good with Array operators.

```
db = [
  {:foo => "bar", :stack => "overflow", :num => 0.5},
  {:foo => "bar", :stack => "underlow", :num => 0.5},
  {:foo => "bar", :stack => "overflow", :num => 0.1}
]

csv = [
  {:foo => "bar", :stack => "overflow", :num => 0.5},
  {:foo => "bar", :stack => "underlow", :num => 0.1},
]

db - csv # => [{:foo=>"bar", :stack=>"underlow", :num=>0.5}, {:foo=>"bar", :stack=>"overflow", :num=>0.1}]
db & csv # => [{:foo=>"bar", :stack=>"overflow", :num=>0.5}]
```

Comment: Hmm - i tried this originally on my data (db = 339 hashes and csv = 10) and (db - csv).count = 339 (when i know the 10 csv hashes are in db. I will check my data more closely...

Comment: Maybe in some hashes keys are symbols and in others - strings. They won't be equal. (just a guess).

Comment: Ive been testing with db[0] == csv[0] which is true, odd

Comment: Turns out my db[0][:num].class = BigDecimal while csv[0][:num].class = Float - fixing that allows me to use - and &