# Performance - Ruby - Compare large array of hashes (dictionary) to primary hash; update resulting value

Tags: ruby, performance, compare

I'm attempting to compare my data, which is in the format of an array of hashes, with another large array of hashes (~50K server names and tags) which serves as a dictionary.  The dictionary is stripped down to only include the absolutely relevant information.

**The code I have works** but it is quite slow on this scale and I haven't been able to pinpoint why.  I've done verbose printing to isolate the issue to a specific statement (tagged via comments below)--when it is commented out, the code runs ~30x faster.

After reviewing the code extensively, I feel like I'm doing something wrong and perhaps `Array#select` is not the appropriate method for this task.  Thank you so much in advance for your help.

**Code:**

```
inventory = File.read('inventory_with_50k_names_and_associate_tag.csv')

# Since my CSV is headerless, I'm forcing manual headers
@dictionary_data = CSV.parse(inventory).map do |name|
  Hash[ [:name, :tag].zip(name) ]
end

# ...
# API calls to my app to return an array of hashes is not shown (returns '@app_data')
# ...

@app_data.each do |issue| 

  # Extract base server name from FQDN (e.g. server_name1.sub.uk => server_name1)
  derived_name = issue['name'].split('.').first

  # THIS IS THE BLOCK OF CODE that slows down execution 30 fold:
  @dictionary_data.select do |src_server|
    issue['tag'] = src_server[:tag] if src_server[:asset_name].start_with?(derived_name)
  end

end
```

**Sample Data Returned from REST API (@app_data):**

```
@app_data = [{'name' => 'server_name1.sub.emea', 'tag' => 'Europe', 'state' => 'Online'}
             {'name' => 'server_name2.sub.us', 'tag' => 'US E.', 'state' => 'Online'}
             {'name' => 'server_name3.sub.us', 'tag' => 'US W.', 'state' => 'Failover'}]
```

**Sample Dictionary Hash Content:**

```
@dictionary_data = [{:asset_name => 'server_name1-X98765432', :tag => 'Paris, France'}
                    {:asset_name => 'server_name2-Y45678920', :tag => 'New York, USA'}
                    {:asset_name => 'server_name3-Z34534224', :tag => 'Portland, USA'}]
```

**Desired Output:**

```
@app_data = [{'name' => 'server_name1', 'tag' => 'Paris, France', 'state' => 'Up'}
             {'name' => 'server_name2', 'tag' => 'New York, USA', 'state' => 'Up'}
             {'name' => 'server_name3', 'tag' => 'Portland, USA', 'state' => 'F.O'}]
```

Comment: Indeed, `Array#select` should be wrong here - its block should return a boolean value, it would not typically have side effects like assignments, and you should care about `Array#select`'s return value. You might want `Array#each` here, but it's difficult to tell since you never tell us what you *intend* the code to do; then we could maybe advise a better way for you do do it.

Comment: Rather than an array of hashes for the "hash content", consider constructing a single hash: `{ 'server_name1' => 'Paris, France',   'server_name2' => 'New York, USA'',   'server_name3' => 'Portland, USA' }`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys, sorry that I maybe wasn't clear enough. Amadan, I'm basically overwriting the default tag in the data returned by my application's API with the tag in my dictionary csv file (if and only if the server name matches in both my data and the dictionary data). Does that make sense? Thank you! Cary, that's a wonderful idea, I'll give it a shot and see if performance is considerably better. Thanks!

Comment: I just happened to see your comment directed to @Amadan and me. Because I put an ampersand before Amadan's name, SO will notify him of my comment. Without that he may never see it. You are limited to one name with an ampersand per comment. You could have left separate comments for Amadan and me, each with our name preceded by an  ampersand, Abbreviations are permitted. For example,  if you pretend for a moment that `&` is an ampersand (since I've already used my allotment in this comment), you could have written `&Cary`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: "if you pretend for a moment that `&` is an ampersand" lol... [`&`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampersand) *is* an ampersand (from "... and - per se - 'and'"). You're talking about [`@`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_sign), typically called "at-sign", or more formally "commercial at". And just to be clear, yes, as shown by both Cary and me, notifying someone is done by the latter, `@` (at-sign). :)

Comment: @KurtW It does make sense but the devil is in the details (mostly because you might have some not-quite-equality ideas on what "matches" means, based on your talk of `derived_server_name`. Can you please construct a minimal example where all of this comes into play, including both input arrays *and* (the most important bit) a desired output?

Comment: As a certain esteemed leader might write, "I never said '&' was an ampersand! Amadan, BAD!"

Comment: Is it possible for you to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11796303/5594180) logic?

Comment: Thank you @Cary Swoveland - - I appreciate it!

Comment: @Amadan, I will modify my question to properly show input and desired output. Thanks!

Comment: Are `server_name1` etc. always unique? Can there be a situation where dictionary data has e.g. `foo-X98765432` and `foo-Y12345678` (`foo` being same)? Can there be a situation where app data has e.g. `foo.sub.us` and `foo.sub.emea` (`foo` being same)? If yes, what do you expect to happen? EDIT: Can it happen that a server in app data matches no entries in dictionary data? If yes, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: @Amadan, thank you so much for your continued help.  Good questions and thank you for thinking ahead, I'll be more explicit in the future with my SO questions.    Yes, `server_name1` in both data sets will only appear once.  No, `@dictionary_data` will always have a unique server name (e.g. `foo` will NOT appear twice - furthermore, foo often appears by itself without the appended `-X98765432`.  No, we'll never see a `foo.sub.us` and a `foo.sub.emea`.  Finally, Yes, there are times where the dictionary will have no match--in these cases, the hash value in `@app_data["tag"]` should not change.

Comment: @Amadan, just to be clear, will the approach you've described drop the rest of the content in `@app_data`?  I've only shown 3 fields (`name`, `tag`, and `state`) for brevity but there are many more and they should remain as-is.  Please also see the answers to your questions regarding unique values above.  Thanks again!

Comment: @CarySwoveland, your suggestion to drop my dictionary to a single hash instead of an array of hashes was actually brillant and could even be considered a solution to my problem.  I appreciate the detailed answer Amadan gave and will likely mark it correct and it will solve more people's questions in the future.  Looking back on it, I suppose iterating over an array of hashes for every loop wasn't a good call for performance.  Is comparing a string value to a single hash instead of an array of hashes that much different?  It's like 30x faster this way!

Comment: Kurt, yes, the difference is like night and day. Hash lookups are lightning fast compared to stepping through arrays.  [This wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) explains why hash lookups are so fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming "no" on both of my questions in the comments:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'csv'

@dictionary_data = CSV.open('dict_data.csv') { |csv|
  Hash[csv.map { |name, tag| [name[/^.+(?=-\w+$)/], tag] }]
}

@app_data = [{'name' => 'server_name1.sub.emea', 'tag' => 'Europe', 'state' => 'Online'},
             {'name' => 'server_name2.sub.us', 'tag' => 'US E.', 'state' => 'Online'},
             {'name' => 'server_name3.sub.us', 'tag' => 'US W.', 'state' => 'Failover'}]

STATE_MAP = {
  'Online' => 'Up',
  'Failover' => 'F.O.'
}

@app_data = @app_data.map do |server|
  name = server['name'][/^[^.]+/]
  {
    'name' => name,
    'tag' => @dictionary_data[name],
    'state' => STATE_MAP[server['state']],
  }
end

p @app_data
# => [{"name"=>"server_name1", "tag"=>"Paris, France", "state"=>"Up"}, 
#    {"name"=>"server_name2", "tag"=>"New York, USA", "state"=>"Up"}, 
#    {"name"=>"server_name3", "tag"=>"Portland, USA", "state"=>"F.O."}]
```

EDIT: I find it more convenient here to read the CSV without headers, as I don't want it to generate an array of hashes. But to read a headerless CSV as if it had headers, you don't need to touch the data itself, as Ruby's CSV is quite powerful:

```
CSV.read('dict_data.csv', headers: %i(name tag)).map(&:to_hash)
```